# Android Gridview and getChildAt with NullPointerException

Tags: android, gridview, button, nullpointerexception, adapter

I have a UI that consists of a Gridview loaded with a custom adapter.  A ButtonAdapter, in this case.  So the grid loads fine, the button clicks function like I want them to, but now I have to indicate on the button that it the "active" selection.

I thought I'd do this by just keeping track and changing the background. As it turns out, and based on a couple posts here on SO, the buttons don't actually exist when they are off screen...and even immediately after a scroll.  I'll often get a NullPointerException when trying to change a button background after scrolling.

I've tried changing the views in the adapter to RadioButtons and ToggleButtons, but they all offer similar limitations.

The problem seems mostly to do with the getChildAt() that I use on the grid to "unselect" one button, or whatever, when another one is selected.

Is there a workaround for this, or perhaps another suggestion of similar functionality.  A vertically scrollable, grid-like format, etc...

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
Thanks Craigy...I did forget to put a platform on there o.0...i'll add android.

Comment: where is your button click function in? In the getView of the adapter or in onItemClickListener of the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using a [Selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)?  In ignorance of how your buttonAdapter works or what you're pulling it from, you can set the background drawable of any View to change according to its state using selectors.

If your selector is defined like so (assuming the presence of appropriate drawables, of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_activated="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_selected" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

And then set your GridView's choice mode to single Choice:

```
<GridView
   ...
   android:choiceMode="singleChoice" />
```

This lets the OS take care of everything for you in terms of remembering which position is selected in the list and then clearing it out for you when you've clicked another one

Comment: I am using a statelist for the buttons. I hadnt thought of this Activated business.In trying it, however, it doesn't seem like mGridView.setActivated(false); does anything.  Nothing's getting cleared.

Comment: Yeah, the app is supporting APIs under 11.  I actually though we had something there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well if you're ever in the honeycomb+ neighborhood again, the actual method call to clear it is dispatchSetActivated().  You might still be able to do what I've described above using the setSelected() call, though, so I wouldn't give up just yet.

Comment: The app supports API 9 and up. This idea seems to have the most potential, but I couldn't get it to "clear" everything. Thanks.

Comment: You can use setSelected, like I said... I haven't personally tried that, though, so there may be quirks I'm not aware of.  but yeah dispatchSetSelected(false) should call setSelected(false) on all of the view's children

Comment: Took another stab at it - this might be closer (and a lot cleaner)

Comment: :D Where do I send the hug! This is perfect. Excellent solution.  Thanks so much for sticking with it.

Comment: Any last bits of wisdom in defaulting a button to the Selected state on the getView of the adapter load? setSelected(true) doesn't seem to want to do it. I also threw in setActivated(true), no help.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you're looking for setItemChecked(position, true)

Comment: That'll set it to start off, but dispatch doesn't clear that. and if in onClick I try setItemChecked = false it gives nullpointer again because it's trying to access a specific view that might not be there/ready. Argh, so close...

Comment: sigh...that doesn't seem to work either. I hate being at 90%...thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Set a tag on each of the views that the adapter creates in getView(). Later search for the view with that tag by gridView.findViewByTag() or get the view's tag by view.getTag().

Comment: No, this has the same issue because I have to locate the previous button clicked to change it back to "unclicked" color before changing the current button to the "clicked" color. And I still get NullPointers sometimes interacting with the previous button. Thanks though.

Comment: a previous can return null if it is scrolled of screen and has been recycled.  so as long as I check for nulls, this is a good solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this may not perfectly answer your question but I had done something sort of similar.  Basically, I added items to a table and needed to have a remove button associated with the item.  When the remove button was clicked, it needed to remove only that item from the table. This could be adapted to your needs so rather than removing the item clicked, it finds the previous item, unclicks it, and then highlights then newly clicked one.

So what I did was give a tag to the buttons themselves (obviously they need to be unique).  When a button is clicked, save its tag in something like a sharedPreference for later reference.  Then when a new button is clicked, simply find the button with the previously clicked tag and unmark the row that it is in and then mark the row for the newly clicked button.  Here is the code I used (sorry the variable names are terrible, I actually had this working in a test app that was never released so I didn't bother giving them better names):

```
        //Previous button clicked
        String id = <get this from wherever you choose to store it>
        // create a new TableRow
        TableRow row = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

        TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        t.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        t.setText(unique);

        Button b = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            { 
                for(int i = 0; i < table.getChildCount(); i++)
                {          
                    TableRow row = (TableRow) table.getChildAt(i);                        
                    Button bt = (Button) row.getChildAt(1);
                    TextView view  = (TextView)row.getChildAt(0);

                    if( id.equals(v.getTag())) //they match, so this is the button that was previously clicked
                    {
                        //Put your code here to unclick the previous button and mark the new one as clicked.                            

                    }
                }  
            }
        });   

        b.setText(R.string.removeButtonText);
        b.setTag(t.getText().toString());

        /***BE SURE TO SAVE THE NEW BUTTON TAG (t.getText().toString()) SOMEWHERE LIKE A SHARED PREFERENCE****/
        //saving the tag

        //add the row to the table                
        row.addView(t);
        row.addView(b);        
        // add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        table.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Again, I don't suspect this is the exact answer you are looking for, but maybe it will give you an idea to try out.  Hopefully this makes some sense, if not please feel free to ask for clarification.  Sorry if it is way off base as well.

Comment: Actually, this is very much like the first response below. I've tried the tags and there are still NullPointer problems with the Views sometimes.  Like if the one to be "unselected" is off the screen or clicking too fast through the various buttons, etc. Thanks though.